# CNN -> LSTM cascaded models to PyTorch Lightning

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to covert PyTorch code for CNN -> LSTM cascaded models to PyTorch Lightning.
There are two nn.Module classes in the PyTorch code, one for CNN (encoder) and one for LSTM (decoder); the last hidden layer of CNN is used as input to LSTM.

So, after conversion to PyTorch Lightning, there are two pl.LightningModule classes. I want to know how to populate the required methods in these two classes viz. forward(), training_step(), train_dataloader() and configure_optimizers().

Here are loss and optimizer definitions in PyTorch; optimizer uses parameters from both encoder and decoder models:

```
   loss_criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    parameters = list(decoder_model.parameters()) + list(encoder_model.linear_layer.parameters()) + list(encoder_model.batch_norm.parameters())
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(parameters, lr=0.001)
```

Here is the relevant PyTorch code from nested for training loop, encoder output is fed as input to the decoder and then the loss is calculated using the decoder output:

```
feats = encoder_model(imgs)
outputs = decoder_model(feats, caps, lens)
loss = loss_criterion(outputs, tgts)
decoder_model.zero_grad()
encoder_model.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to have a "wrapper" model that instantiates and uses the CNN & LSTM models. CNN & LSTM models don't to subclass `pl.LightningModule` in this case. They can remain as `nn.Module`. An example structure will be as follows:

```
class WrapperModel(pl.LightningModule):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_model = EncoderModel()
        self. decoder_model = DecoderModel()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        <initialize optimizers>

    def forward(self, imgs, caps, lens):
        feats = self.encoder_model(imgs)
        outputs = self.decoder_model(feats, caps, lens)
        return outputs

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        imgs, caps, lens, tgts = batch
        outputs = self.forward(imgs, caps, lens)

        loss = loss_criterion(outputs, tgts)
        return loss
```